# Displaying an ImageIcon in a JList that uses a different Object to load the JList data

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer, imageicon

I have a JList that is being populated through an ArrayList of strings somewhere else, i want to for the same list now display an ImageIcon saved in my directory somewhere. For now i want to display the same icon for any item added to the list (or any items currently in the list).

My list should look like this : **ICON STUDENT NAME ...
                                  ICON STUDENT NAME**

The problem (The image icon shows the correct height and it is being captured but does not show in the list at run-time

Here is my action listener that adds the data to the List.

```
 public class StudentListener implements ActionListener{

   private Main_Menu menu;
   private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();;
   Iterator iterator = arrayList.iterator();
   JList sList;
   Map<Object, Icon> icons = new HashMap<Object, Icon>();        
   /**
    * 
    * @param menu the referenced menu from our main menu
    */
   public StudentListener(Main_Menu menu){
   this.menu = menu;       
   }

   @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    Icon iCon = new ImageIcon("/Project/src/Images/1312046124_picture.png"); // icons
    int iHeight = iCon.getIconHeight();
       icons.put("name", iCon);           
      //add all the students to our List 
          try {
                StudentModel = new Student_Model();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Student_Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    //arrayList = StudentModel.getStudents(); // modify to use an arrayList of string
    arrayList.add("John");
    arrayList.add("Smith");
    iterator = arrayList.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){          
       System.out.println(iterator.next().toString());
    }
    sList = this.menu.getStudentList();
    sList.setListData(arrayList.toArray());
    sList.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
    System.out.println("height of icon " + iHeight); // displays the correct height
    sList.setCellRenderer(new IconListRenderer(icons));       
   }   
  }
```

IconListCellRenderer

```
public class IconListRenderer
extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

private Map<Object, Icon> icons = null;

public IconListRenderer(Map<Object, Icon> icons) {
    this.icons = icons;
}

@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
    JList list, Object value, int index,
    boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

    // Get the renderer component from parent class

    JLabel label =
        (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list,
            value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

    // Get icon to use for the list item value

    Icon icon = icons.get(value);

    // Set icon to display for value

    label.setIcon(icon);
    return label;
}
  }
```

Comment: You still have NOT posted an SSCCE! We don't have access to you StuentModel or the IconListRenderer. We don'e even need the StudentModel for a SSCCE. All you need to do is hardcord some student names in your ArrayList. I'm guessing the problem is renderer. **Post a proper SSCCE if you want help**. I'm tired of reminding you every time you post a question.

Comment: I have to agree with camickr: there's really no way we can guess why your code isn't working without some small working example. It's up to you really if you wish to provide an SSCCE -- how much do you need our help?

Comment: @Camickr, no need to get animated i was really close in solving this and thought maybe i was just not using the ListCellRenderer property correctly which is why i posted the referencing code. I will update my post to get a better response.

Comment: @Warz, Apparently I do need to get animated because you still don't grasp the concept that you are wasting our time by not posting a proper question will all the information needed to solve the problem. So far you've wasted the time of 21 people who took the time to view the question. By definition when you have a problem you don't know what is causing the problem so you don't know what code is relevant to post, which is why you narrow the problem down by creating a SSCCE.

Comment: @camickr, like i said before i debugged the program as much as i could in order to narrow down where i thought the problem might be, that is what i have posted. I understand that does not do much for the person trying to comprehend the problem and so I will do a better job of posting questions that are "Runnable".

Comment: @Warz, you still haven't posted a SSCCE. The updated code is of no help. Adding hard coded data, when we can't exeucte the program still doesn't help. Hardcoded data means you crate a frame and display the list so we can see what you are talking about and what the renderer is actually doing. You are still wasting everybodys time.

Answer (score 1):

`JList` has method how to add Icon/ImageIcon to the [ListCellRenderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer), link for example is about [JComboBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) that contains `JList`, another examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/List.htm) and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ComplexRenderingSampleListCellRenderer.htm)